# why is the ping not working?

Tags: linux, networking

The network setup is as is seen in the picture:

[image: network setup]

- machine m1's eth0 ethernet port connects to machine m2 eth0 ethernet port via a cross wire.
- machine m1 and m2 are on the same network: `1.1.1.0/24`
- M1 eth0 has address `1.1.1.1/24`, and these entries were entered into the routing table:

  ```
  # ip route add 2.2.2.0/24 via 1.1.1.4 //route to m3
  # ip route add 3.3.3.0/24 via 1.1.1.3 //route to m4
  ```
- Machine M2 has 3 ethernet cards and acts as a router to machine m3 and machine m4 which are on the networks 2.2.2.0/24 and 3.3.3.0/24 respectively.
- M2 has net.ipv4.ip_forward=1 in sysctl.conf
- M2 eth0 has address `1.1.1.2/24`, eth1 has `1.1.1.4/24`, eth2 has `1.1.1.3/24`. These are the commands executed on m2 to enable routing to make all the networks communicate

  ```
  # ip route add 2.2.2.0/24 via 1.1.1.4 //route to m3
  # ip route add 3.3.3.0/24 via 1.1.1.3 //route to m4
  ```
- M3 eth0 has address `2.2.2.1/24`, and these entries were entered onto to the routing table:

  ```
  # ip route add 1.1.1.0/24 via 2.2.2.1 //route to m2 && m1
  # ip route add 3.3.3.0/24 via 2.2.2.1 //route to m4
  ```
- M4 eth0 has address `3.3.3.1/24`, and these entries were entered onto to the routing table

  ```
  # ip route add 2.2.2.0/24 via 3.3.3.1 //route to m3
  # ip route add 1.1.1.0/24 via 3.3.3.1 //route to m2 && m1
  ```

So the first problem is,

- I can ping M1, M3 and M4 from M2.
- I can ping M2 from M3 and M4
- Ping is NOT working from M3 to M4, or from M4 to M3.
- Ping is also NOT working from M1 to M3 or M4.
- Ping is also NOT working from M3/M4 to M1.

what I'm I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

M1 has no route to the 1.1.1.4 (or .3) address since it is a direct connect to .2 .

If you look at the routing table on M1, it will look something like

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
1.1.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

And so it thinks it should be able to connect directly to the 1.1.1.3|4 addresses via a switch or hub.

Put the link between M1 and M2 onto a different subnet, and use M2's address as the default gateway for M1 and it will work.

Same situation exists with the connections from M3/4 to the others, they need to know what route to take, or their default routers need to know.

Answer (score 0):

I think your first problem is that you expect routes to be multi-hop – they will not be. For example, you used these commands on M1, and it seems you're expecting them to choose specific outbound interfaces on M2:

```
# ip route add 2.2.2.0/24 via 1.1.1.4 //route to m3
# ip route add 3.3.3.0/24 via 1.1.1.3 //route to m4
```

That won't happen. Both route entries will only forward the packet to M2's MAC address (as it's the host which answers ARP queries for both nexthop addresses), but M2 decides entirely on its own where to forward those packets next.

So routes added to M1 should've just used M2's address facing M1, i.e. `via 1.1.1.2`.

---

Your second problem is that M2 has three interfaces *belonging to the same network* (1.1.1.0/24).

Instead, because M2 is a router and belongs to all three networks at once, it should have addresses *from those networks:* that is, `2.2.2.x/24` on eth1 and `3.3.3.x/24` on eth2.

(With that, you wouldn't even need to add any routes on M2 – the local-subnet routes would suffice.)

---

Your third problem is that your routes on M3 and M4 do not specify a gateway to send packets through. They only have the host's *own* address, but do not indicate in any way that packets "to M1" must actually go through M2.

Because the routes do not specify a valid gateway/nexthop, they are treated as local-subnet routes; in other words, you're telling M3/M4 that the destination (M1) is available on the local ethernet, even though it isn't. So when you ping M1 from M3/M4, they try to resolve M1's IP address using ARP (which of course fails).

(Remember that Ethernet always works a switched medium, not point-to-point, so M2 will receive *only* those packets which were specifically sent to M2's MAC address (or broadcast). In other words, M2 must be specified as the gateway for route to M1.)

If you have already fixed M2's IP addresses according to part II, then routes on M3/M4 should look like this:

```
(On M3)
# ip addr add 2.2.2.1/24 dev eth0
# ip route add 1.1.1.0/24 via 2.2.2.x  // <via M2's eth1 address>
# ip route add 3.3.3.0/24 via 2.2.2.x  // <via M2's eth1 address>

(On M4)
# ip addr add 3.3.3.1/24 dev eth0
# ip route add 1.1.1.0/24 via 3.3.3.x  // <via M2's eth2 address>
# ip route add 2.2.2.0/24 via 3.3.3.x  // <via M2's eth2 address>
```